# How to use simple-json with intergers in type-graphql

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, graphql, typegraphql

I tried many different things to use simple-json as a type with integers on entities.

```
@ObjectType()
@Entity()
export default class PlayerEntity extends BaseEntity {
    @Field(() => Int)
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

    @Column()
    @Field()
    username: string;

    @Column({ type: "simple-json" })
    @Field()
    info: Info;
}
```

and Info would've looked something like

```
@InputType()
@ObjectType()
export default class Info {
    @Field()
    address: string;

    @Field(() => Int)
    house_number: number;
}
```

Comment: "custom json scalar" ... graphql-type-json ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use GraphQL JSON scalar, e.g. the one from `graphql-type-json` library.